# Android Dialog doesn't go back to bottom when softkeyboard is dismissed

Tags: android, dialog

I have made a custom dialog with an EditText that is shown from the bottom and pushed up when softkeyboard is open:

```
    final Dialog priceFilterDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFilter);

    View priceFilterView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.view_price_filter, null);
    priceFilterDialog.setContentView(priceFilterView); // your custom view.
    priceFilterDialog.setCancelable(true);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

The problem is that when the user dismiss the keyboard the Dialog doesn't return back to the bottom but it stays on the middle of the screen, where it was pushed up by the keyboard.

My `R.layout.view_price_filter`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cl_filter"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <!-- Dialog content here -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What should I do to make the dialog returning to the bottom when the keyboard is dismissed?

EDIT: More code requested:

Everything described above is happening inside the fragment `SearchFragment` that is called by the activity in this way:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements
SearchFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
ProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
ChatsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
ApplicationsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    final Fragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    final Fragment applicationsFragment = new ApplicationsFragment();
    final Fragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
    final Fragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment selectedFragment = searchFragment;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            //Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_search:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(selectedFragment).show(searchFragment).commit();
                    selectedFragment = searchFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_applications:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(selectedFragment).show(applicationsFragment).commit();
                    selectedFragment = applicationsFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_chats:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(selectedFragment).show(chatsFragment).commit();
                    selectedFragment = chatsFragment;
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(selectedFragment).show(profileFragment).commit();
                    selectedFragment = profileFragment;
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, profileFragment, "2").hide(profileFragment).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, chatsFragment, "3").hide(chatsFragment).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, applicationsFragment, "4").hide(applicationsFragment).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, searchFragment, "1").commit();

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
}

}
```

This is what happening inside the fragment:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public SearchFragment() {
    
}

public static SearchFragment newInstance() {
    SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    // Other unrelated code
    
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = this.getLayoutInflater();

    // Price Filter
    final Dialog priceFilterDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFilter);
    
    View priceFilterView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.view_price_filter, null);
    priceFilterDialog.setContentView(priceFilterView); // your custom view.
    priceFilterDialog.setCancelable(true);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    priceFilterDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    
    // Other unrelated code
    
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

Comment: instead of setting it to the dialogwidow you could directly set it from manifest ...as an attribute to the activity tab !

Comment: I tried with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` on the manifest activity attributes but still it doesn't return to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You code from above (in clean/pure) app works as it should (dialog is going down):

[image]

Comment: I did try but still it doesn't return to the bottom. Does the fact that this is happening inside a fragment change anything?

Comment: If you are able to find the issue in the code I uploaded it would be very helpful for me!

Comment: @Gicminos you have to upload somewhere whole your app.